# How to edit Attribute Node in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, extjs

I am getting my dom element

```
var AB = this.triggers.clear.getEl().dom;
```

This is my dom element
**AB**

```
<div id=​"gridcolumn-1024-filter-trigger-clear" class=​"x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-default button-cross button-cross-default  ">​…​</div>​
```

In that I am taking class

```
var ABC = this.triggers.clear.getEl().dom.getAttributeNode("class")
```

This is my class
**ABC**

```
class=​"x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-default button-cross button-cross-default  "
```

Now I want to edit my class which will be like

```
class=​" button-cross button-cross-default  "
```

Can any body please suggest me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and its `remove()` method

```
AB.classList.remove('x-form-trigger').remove('x-form-trigger-default')
```

OR, Using [Element.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

```
AB.className = "button-cross button-cross-default"
```

Comment: Thank yOu SatPal. Worked like charm